# Codeception failure screenshots

Tags: automation, codeception

Codeception plugin Recorder saves all the steps till failure if tests fails. e.g.

01.png - Success

02.png - Success

03.png - Failure

Is there any way how can I only save 03.png failure screenshot without having success screens saved along ?
Thank you in advanced

Codeception: v2.2.2

PhantomJS as webdriver: v2.1

Answer (score 1):

> `delete_successful` (default: true) - delete records for successfully passed tests (log only failed and errored)

from: http://codeception.com/addons#configuration